# Azure CSV Import to update users Password Never Expire

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, foreach, service-accounts

I'm trying to import a CSV file to do a bulk service accounts and change to password never expire in Azure. I think it loop is called foreach.

```
$connect = Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $env:USERNAME@company.com
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId test01@company.com -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
```

Comment: I'm trying to do an import of a CSV file that has multiple service accounts that need to be updated that are currently in Azure to set Password Never Expire. The original script works, but only for one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it loop is called foreach

Yes, Use the **`foreach`** to do bulk operation.

#### Workaround follows:

```
# you can use the below code for bulk opertation
Import-CSV "<user file>" | foreach {
 Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.UserPrincipalName -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
}
```

#### Result

[image]
Changes applied in Azure AD
[image]